# Bash script for searching and replacing tags

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file have lots of string tags like `</usr/share/some_pattern>`, all they have in common is they all begin with a `<` and end with a `>`, how can write a bash script to remove all these tags(including the strings inside)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' file
```

Comment: Besides Philipp's answer (which is automated), you could also do it in vi, using the same regular expresion:


1-`vi filename.txt` 
2-`(enter in command mode by pressing ESC key)` 
3-`type :%s/<[^>]*>//g` 
4-`to save&quit vi :wq`

Comment: Or in Emacs: `M-x replace-regexp RET <[^>]*> RET RET C-x C-s C-x C-c`